# Java http GET path routed to wrong API

Tags: java, http, path, get, jax-rs

Background: we upgraded spring from 2.x to 4.x to resolve a security vulerability. This also involved upgrading jaxrs, resteasy, hibernate, and a bunch of other stuff. So one of these components broke something.

The problem is:

```
@GET
@Path("/ns/rating/ascsv/{valid}")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
String getAllNettingSetRating(@PathParam("valid") String valid);
```

is being routed incorrectly to

```
@GET
@Path("ns/{nsid}/{valid}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
AgreementResponse getAgreementByNettingSetId(
        @PathParam("nsid") String nsid, 
        @PathParam("valid") String valid);
```

Where "rating" gets passed in as {nsid} and "ascsv" is passed in as {valid}

In other words, the user is calling ".../ns/rating/ascsv/20190830" but it is routing to the method for "ns/{nsid}/{valid}", and our static strings "rating" and "ascsv" are being passed in as params for the wrong api.

Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Could you please help me with the Curl command? the full URI invoked by the client?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran the user will call this: .../ns/rating/ascsv/20190830 but it is going to the method to handle ns/{nsid}/{valid}

Comment: Do you specify any 'Accept-Language' in client code?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran I do not see it in our codebase

Comment: As per my understanding, if the controller has the handler methods like `/ns/rating/ascsv/{valid}` and `ns/{nsid}/{valid}` then the request `.../ns/rating/ascsv/20190830` should be directed to `/ns/rating/ascsv/{valid}` method. Because Spring gives priority to the exact String in the path than the Path variable so `rating` should have been the priority than `{nsid}` path variable

Comment: Yes that is my understanding too... I have no idea why it is being routed the way it currently is.

Comment: Sorry I supposed to ask the `Accept` header value in your client usage. Because as per your comment you have not specified any `Accept` Header in your codebase, so in such case the JAX-RS default `Accept` values would have been added when make an HTTP request. `application/xml` is one of the default type so if you specify the `text/plain` Accept value then your request will be routed to expected handler method.

Comment: Thanks @PrasanthRajendran. I do not see any header accept values.

Answer (score 0):

With SpringBoot use [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html).

In a more concicse way you can use

```
@RequestMapping(value="ns/{nsid}/{valid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
AgreementResponse getAgreementByNettingSetId(
        @PathVariable("nsid") String nsid, 
        @PathVariable("valid") String valid) {
// your code here
}
```

Comment: We are not on spring boot, can it still work? I see in our libaries that PathVariable class is indeed available here: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable

Comment: Yes it should because [Spring can start a rest controller alone](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web) even if with SpringBoot is simpler.

Comment: I changed our two problem APIs to use @PathVariable, still seeing the same result. Next I am thinking i need to update resteasy-cache-core, resteasy-multipart-provider, resteasy-jettison-provider from 1.x to 3.x

Comment: I am thinking that if you use resteasy as REST controller you are bound to JAX-RS which makes my Spring annotation useless. At this point the only difference that I can spot is the "/" in the first `@Path` and not in the second. I am aware of Java `@Path` specifications ("leading '/' in a path is ignored") but the final implementation is given by resteasy.

Comment: Thanks, we fixed that extra '/' but there is no difference!